# Trying to format string of Datagrid output

Tags: c#, telerik-grid

Hi i have the following which creates two worksheets in an excel spreadsheet based on the values in a datagrid, I am able to get it working for two datagrids, however i need to do it for 14 datagrids, this is what i have got so far;

```
  var grid1Output = RadGridView1.ToExcelML();
  var grid2Output = RadGridView2.ToExcelML().Replace("Worksheet1", "Worksheet2");

  var workBook = grid1Output.Replace("</Worksheet>", "</Worksheet>" + 
       grid2Output.Substring(grid2Output.IndexOf("<Worksheet"), 
       grid2Output.IndexOf("</Worksheet")- grid2Output.IndexOf("<Worksheet")) + "        </Worksheet>");
```

The above works fine, however I need to do it for 14 gridoutputs in total. My problem is, I am having trouble replacing strings at the right place. How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do it with Linq for XML methods rather than string manipulation, but the choice is yours.

Either way, it shouldn't be that hard to write a method that takes a grid output (I am assuming it's a string), extracts the contents, and returns them.  The calling routine then assembles the 14 XML strings and wraps them in a single Worksheet tag.

Here's a stab at it.  Bear in mind that I'm not familiar with the RadGridView and the output of ToExcelML, so you probably won't be able to use this code without some modification.  I'm making some assumptions that may not be valid.

First, I would create a method that takes an XML string as input.  I am assuming that this string is entirely wrapped in a <Worksheet*n*> tag.

```
string ExtractWorksheetContents(string excelML, int index)
{
// You might also be able to do this with a regex, depending on how the contents are structured
// Since I don't know enough about the content, I will do this with string manipulation, as
// you did, rather than loading the XML and making assumptions.

    string tagName = string.Format("Worksheet{0}", index);        
    int worksheetStart = excelML.IndexOf("<" + tagName);
    int worksheetEnd = excelML.IndexOf("</" + tagName + ">") + tagName.Length + 3);
    // Should contain some checks that neither w'sheet start nor end are -1
    return excelML.Substring(worksheetStart, worksheetEnd-worksheetStart);
}
```

Then I would assemble the results.  Again, I'm making assumptions about how the XML is structured.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<Worksheet>");
RadGridView[] gridViews = new RadGridView[] { RadGridView1, RadGridView2 .... RadGridView14 };
for(int i=0;i<14; i++)
{
    var rgv = gridViews[i];
    sb.Append(ExtractWorksheetContents(rgv.ToExcelML(),i+1));
}
sb.Append("</Worksheet>");
var workBook = sb.ToString();
```

Hope this helps somewhat.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding, i have no idea on how this method would look or work, please if possible give me a sample. thanks